# Getting error: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Row'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am working on the project wherein I am currently upgrading the dependencies versions like flask, sqlalchemy etc. I've encountered an issue where in the below code is giving error

`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Row'`

**Existing code:**

```
def get_by_ids(model, id_list, field='uuid'):
    field = getattr(model, field)
    items = Database.get_session().query(model).filter(field.in_(id_list))
    return items.all()
Here,
id_list =  [('hskzmjosomxj',), ('f7l708nhrbwk',), ('di8cucj8pdbh',), ('p3kqrdnkupby',)]
field = Bucket.key , type <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute'>
model = Bucket
```

The above snippet is working fine with sqlalchemy 1.3.24 version but giving the error with sqlalchemy 2.0.4 version.

If I don't use `.filter(field.in_(id_list))` then, all() function is working fine and not giving that error. I have checked everything but I am not able to resolve this error.

Do I need to register adaptor to convert 'Row' to python data type?

Comment: 1) You have jumped over 1.4 to 2.x. I would say you need to spend some time here [2.0 Migration](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html#the-1-4-2-0-migration-path). 2) What version of `psycopg2`?

Comment: You might try: `id_list =  ('hskzmjosomxj', 'f7l708nhrbwk', 'di8cucj8pdbh', 'p3kqrdnkupby')`

Comment: Works for me SQLA 2.0.4, psycopg2 2.9.5.

Comment: Thanks All. I have figured out the actual issue. id_list which looks like a list of tuple objects is rather a list of Row objects (Row displays like tuple). As Row object is not adaptable to Psycopg2 hence, I need to change it to any acceptable data type like list

Comment: @PuneetJain your answer here was very helpful, please add it as a full answer post.

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP's answer in the comments:

> `id_list` looks like a list of tuples, but really is a list of Row objects (Row displays like tuple).
> As `Row` objects are not adaptable to Psycopg2, they need to be changed to any acceptable data type, like `list`.